# Prevent child elements for receiving click event not working

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to make a modal component and dismiss it when I click outside of the component. Here is my current setup:

1. **Auth** component with click event set on a `div` element:

```
    <template>   <div>
        <transition name="modal">
          <div class="modal-mask" @click="$parent.$emit('close')">
            <div class="modal-wrapper">
              <div class="modal-container">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <slot name="header">Default Header</slot>
                </div>
                <div class="model-body">
                  <slot name="body">Default Body</slot>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <slot name="footer">Default Footer</slot>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </transition>   </div> </template>
```

2. **SignIn** component that injects necessary information:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <Auth />
  </div>
</template>
```

3. **Home** component that uses the SignIn component:

```
<template>
  <div class="home">
    <SignIn v-if="showModal" @close="showModal = false" />
  </div>
</template>
```

Right now when I click outside the modal it behaves ok, the `close` event is called.
But it is also called when I click inside the modal.

Not I tried to use `@click.self` , but now it doesn't work anymore even when clicking outside the modal.

```
      <div class="modal-mask" @click.self="$parent.$emit('close')">
```

I am currently learning **VueJs**, but I don't understand how this works. I thought `self` will prevent propagating click event to child elements and thats it.

Anyone has an idea what is going on ?

PS: I am using this setup, because I want to have a SignIn and SignUp using the Auth component.

Comment: Have you tried using @click.stop on your modal-wrapper?

Comment: Yes, with stop it will disappear when clicking outside and inside modal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either `<div class="modal-wrapper">` or `<div class="modal-container">` needs `@click.prevent.stop`

```html
<template>

   <div>

        <transition name="modal">

          <div class="modal-mask" @click="$parent.$emit('close')">

            <div class="modal-wrapper">

              <div class="modal-container" @click.prevent.stop>

                <div class="modal-header">
                  <slot name="header">Default Header</slot>
                </div>

                <div class="model-body">
                  <slot name="body">Default Body</slot>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <slot name="footer">Default Footer</slot>
                </div>

              </div>

            </div>

          </div>

        </transition>

    </div>

</template>
```

Comment: You were right, <div class="modal-container"> needs a @click.prevent.stop. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With this code you don't have to worry about click event's propagation `@click.stop`, for the **style** purpose I am using bootstrap.css but you can write your own style.

Here is the reusable component BsModal.vue

```
<template lang="pug">
  div(v-if="showModal")
    .modal.fade.d-block(tabindex='-1', role='dialog', :class="{'show': addShowClassToModal}")
      .modal-dialog(role='document')
        .modal-content.border-0
          .modal-header.border-0
            h5.modal-title
              slot(name="title")
            button.close(type='button', data-dismiss='modal', aria-label='Close', @click="hideModal")
              span &times;
          .modal-body.p-0
            slot
    .modal-backdrop.fade(:class="{ 'show': addShowClassToModalBackdrop }")
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'BsModal',
  props: {
    showModal: {
      default: false,
      type: Boolean,
    },
  },

  data() {
    return {
      addShowClassToModal: false,
      addShowClassToModalBackdrop: false,
    };
  },

  mounted() {
    this.toggleBodyClass('addClass', 'modal-open');

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.addShowClassToModalBackdrop = true;
    }, 100);
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.addShowClassToModal = true;
    }, 400);
  },

  destroyed() {
    this.toggleBodyClass('removeClass', 'modal-open');
  },

  methods: {
    hideModal() {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.addShowClassToModal = false;
      }, 100);

      setTimeout(() => {
        this.addShowClassToModalBackdrop = false;
        this.$emit('hide-modal', false);
      }, 400);
    },
    toggleBodyClass(addRemoveClass, className) {
      const elBody = document.body;

      if (addRemoveClass === 'addClass') {
        elBody.classList.add(className);
      } else {
        elBody.classList.remove(className);
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

And use it wherever you need by importing it:

```
<template lang="pug">
  div
    button(@click="showModal = true")
      | Show Modal
    bs-modal(
      v-if="showModal",
      :show-modal="showModal",
      @hide-modal="showModal = false"
    ).modal
      template(slot="title") Modal Title
      // Modal Body content here
</template>

<script>
import BsModal from '~/components/BsModal.vue';

export default {
  name: 'your component',
  components: { BsModal },

  data() {
    return {
      showModal: false,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

If you don't like `pug` template language then you can convert PUG to HTML here: https://pughtml.com/